# Return last n entries from a column

Tags: google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I was wondering how to return the last n entries from a column in Google Sheets.

I have seen how to return the last entry, but say I wanted to return the last 5 entries.  What formula is best to use?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can return the last n entries with the following logic :

```
=query(Query_formula,"Select * offset "&countif_formula)
```

You also need to know what your `count_formula` is. To filter the last n rows you can use this formula :

```
=countif(B2:B,E2)
```

This is an example based of the following link's use case :

[Filter rows in Google Sheet](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/formula-to-conditionally-filter-last-n-rows-in-google-sheets/)